# Code in Markup for a link-href (.Net)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have an aspx-Page with an anchor-tag. It´s href has to take a parameter of the
page, which is a public member.

```
public int CommissionId
    {
        get
        {
             //..
        }            
    }
```

I know how to design the link in code-behind, but want to do it in Markup.
I tried

```
<a href='<% String.Format(@"Details.aspx?commissionId=" + CommissionId) %>' runat="server" id="cancelLink" class="button" onclick="this.blur();"><span>Back</span></a>
```

but the link doesn´t respond.

Comment: Well, how does it look in the generated HTML? That's the first thing to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
<a href='<%# String.Format(@"Details.aspx?commissionId=" + CommissionId) %>' runat="server" id="cancelLink" class="button" onclick="this.blur();"><span>Back</span></a>
```

And then add to codebehind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataBind();
    }
```

Hope it will help you. Good luck!!

Best regards, Dima.

Answer (score 1):

Try change **<%** to **<%=**. Hope it helps.